# Override property in YAML

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a third party library, that is being configured with the i**mportant-config.yaml** file.

```
prop1: value1
prop2: value2(need to override)
prop3: value3
```

To refer to it I have the next line in **application.properties**:

```
important-config=classpath:important-config.yaml
```

There is a property in yaml-file that depends on environment where app is running. So I need to `override` this property on startup. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I can see three suitable variants to solve it:

1. Override properties directly in application.properties. I think that priority of is is higher that included congig (at least you could try to override property after you place important-config).
2. You can override selected properties using command line directly `java -jar app.jar --prop2="value2"`
3. Or override via system properties `java -Dprop2="value2"-jar app.jar`

Full informaiton you can find here http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Absolute all properties are stored in Spring `Environment` object. You should pay attention on full variable name, because depending on other setting your **prop2** could be store in **xxx.yyy.prop2**.